# Vuestic and Typescript Integration

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuestic, vuestic-admin

I'm new to Vue and Vuestic, and I would like to know if it's possible to integrate Typescript into a Vuestic project. If possible, how can I accomplish it?

Created a new project with Vuestic CLI and ran it without any issues:

> vuestic testproj

> npm install && npm run serve

Then I tried to add Typescript to the project with Vue CLI:

> vue add typescript

> ? Use class-style component syntax? Yes
> ? Use Babel alongside TypeScript (required for modern mode, auto-detected polyfills, transpil ing JSX)? Yes
> ? Convert all .js files to .ts? Yes
> ? Allow .js files to be compiled? Yes
> ? Skip type checking of all declaration files (recommended for apps)? Yes

I get hundreds of errors similar to these:

> Cannot find module './App' or its corresponding type declarations.

> Property 'AD' does not exist on type '{}'

> Cannot find module '../components/admin/AppLayout' or its corresponding type declarations.

> ...

Any idea on how to add Typescript and solve these issues?

Comment: You are trying to add TS to an existing project or you want to create a new one ?

Comment: Since the project was created with Vuestic CLI, i'm trying to add TS to that project. So i guess i'm trying to add it to a existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the can't find module ./App its important to end imports with the proper file ending. example ./App.vue.
Vue typescript projects also requires a shims-vue.d.ts file that you can put in src directory. It should contain:

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import type { DefineComponent } from "vue";
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>;
  export default component;
}
```

I would not recommend using the auto convert all js files to ts files. Do that manually, this way its easier to see where errors are created.